# NSTextView replacement for huge files

Tags: nstextview, replace

NSTextview was not designed for huge files. 
Before I start writing a replacement myself (for simple ascii files) I want to ask if there are already alternatives available to handle these files.
NSTextview is great but if you load a large file > 100 to 200mb it is getting really slow when you scroll down to the end for example.

So, does anyone know of a replacement available?